# Get range from inputbox prompt (wb1), transfer values to defined range (wb2)

Tags: vba, excel

Attempting to write a macro which can help transfer information from thousands of old files to newly formatted files. Most are standard, so I have a macro that can transfer values from specified ranges on the "old" books to specified ranges on the "new" books, relatively pain free (thanks to this site).

However, some of the old files are atypically formatted, and the ranges don't match those specified in my macro. So, I decided it would make sense in these instances to have the user define the range to be copied.

I've tried assigning the values as =, and I've tried copy-pasting, neither works so far. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code so far (this is just one iteration, like I said i've been trying a bunch of different things):

```
sub magic_select()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim vfile As Variant
    Dim name As String
    Dim oldname As String
    Dim Cvalves, Ovalves, breakers, safety_inst, procedure_ID, Pvalves, Pbreakers, electest As String

    'set source workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'open target workbook
    vfile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-Files,*.xls*", _
        1, "Select One File to Open", , False)

    'if nothing selected, exit sub
    If TypeName(vfile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub

    'open selected file
    Workbooks.Open vfile

    'set target workbook
    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

      'procedure_ID = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="select procedure ID: one cell", Type:=8)
       Cvalves = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="select valves to be locked closed", Type:=8)
       Ovalves = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="select valves to be locked open", Type:=8)
       breakers = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="select breakers to be opened and locked out", Type:=8)
       safety_inst = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="select Special Safety Instructions", Type:=8)
       Pvalves = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="select valves from Procedure(page 2)", Type:=8)
      Pbreakers = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="select breakers from Procedure (page2)", Type:=8)
       electest = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="select Electrical Test Procedure", Type:=8)

    'copies all the appropriate values to blank form
    'wb is blank form (copy to)
    'wb2 is old LOTO form (copied from)
    'edit values as needed
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("e11, e85").Value = 
    wb2.Worksheets(1).Range("e11").Value
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("E21:I45").Value = Range("Cvalves").Value
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("E50:I61").Value = Range("Ovalves").Value
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("E95:G121").Value = Range("breakers").Value
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("a124:a128").Value = Range("breakers").Val
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("h70, c132").Value = Range("procedure_ID").Value
    wb.Worksheets(2).Range("a10:f54").Value = Range("Pvalves").Value
    wb.Worksheets(2).Range("a60:f89").Value = Range("Pbreakers").Value
    wb.Worksheets(2).Range("a92:a97").Value = Range("Electest").Value

    name = wb2.name
    oldname = "_done_" & name


    'resaves old file under new name
    wb2.SaveAs Filename:="xyz" & oldname, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    'closes old file
    wb2.Close

    'deletes old duplicate file
    Kill vfile

    'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'saves as new, separate LOTO form
     wb.SaveAs Filename:="zyx" & name, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    're-open blank macro form
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\me.etc")

    'closes new file
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1- The return value of `Application.InputBox(..., Type:=8)` is a `Range object`. So first of all, dim your variables appropriately.

```
Dim Cvalves As Range, Ovalves As Range, breakers As Range, ' etc..
```

2- `Set` the range to the user's selected range:

```
  Set Cvalves = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="select valves to be locked closed", Type:=8)
' ^^^
```

3- Now you can copy the user selected range to the appropriate destination, i.e.

```
CValves.Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("E21")
```

Or you can (preferably) do it without copy by directly assigning values:

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("E21").Resize(CValves.Rows.Count, CValves.Columns.Count).Value = CValves.Value2
```

You need to follow this approach with all the ranges that the user will select. I have a feeling that this approach is error prone because the user has to select so many ranges and may makes mistakes. But if this is the only option, this is how you can implement it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had those dim'd as String as a kind of off the wall attempt, forgot to change that when posting here. I was able to make it work by just assigning values. It is error prone because of the high user input, so I need to spend some time covering that, I'm just glad the values transfer! I'm new to VBA and spent hours trying to get that. Thanks again for the help.